Vin12V or 5V power supply: possible mistakes
I would like to run an arduino Mega, used to control several stepper motors in a photo enlarger made in the 90s, where the motor control pcb is missing.
In this instrument there is the power PCB still working, which provides 25V DC for the motors, 5v DC regulated for the electronics, +12/-12VDC for some analog comparators and 24VAC for the main lamp.
I would like to use the 5VDC or eventually the +12V to power the Mega.
I have 2 doubts:

is it better to use the 5v connected to the +5V pin or the 12V connected to the Vin? Following the original logic of the instrument I think it would be better to use the 5V, since it's dedicated to the electronics for the whole instrument system. But I read in arduino's docs that is not advised and it's conflicting with usb power supply. Is it true? Does it mean that I cannot use a USB connection when Mega is connected to the main instrument +5V?
Regarding the load on Arduino: I'm going to control via I2C an LCD 20x4, 3rotary encoders, 3 DRV8871 and 3 TB660 + 3 limit switches. Both DRV8871 and lcd screen can be powered by the +5v power supply, and tb660 is opto isolated, so the only load is on internal pullup resistors
the original motor control PCB is missing because it was damaged. There are some chances that this is due to faulty power supplied by the power PCB or by the transformer. How can I verify that the power pcb is working and providing stable and regulated power both with no load and under load? I fear that simply measuring the output voltage is not enough. (By the way, I measured the voltage with no load and I got exactly 5V, +12 and -12V, instead the 25 +-1VDC was measured 27V)

Thanks for you help

is it better to use the 5v connected to the +5V pin or the 12V connected to the Vin?  ... the question is not answerable until you say what you mean by better

Depends on how much current you need on 5V. Mega has linear voltage regulator and it'll get hot even with 200mA load (12-5)V*0.2A=1.4W of power turned into heat

I'm going to control via I2C an LCD 20x4, 3rotary encoders, 3 DRV8871 and 3 TB660 + 3 limit switches. Both DRV8871 and lcd screen can be powered by the +5v power supply, and tb660 i think is opto isolated, so the only load is on internal pullup resistors, if I'm right

Please [edit] your question when clarifying and answering comments. -- You might want to measure the current needed by your Mega. -- To further check the power PCB, use some high-power resistors (read: light bulbs) to give it some load. For example, your (spare) car's front-light bulb is an actual fine high-power load, while a torch's bulb takes significant power but a lot lower. Select as needed.

Thanks , edited. I'm planning to measure the current needed by the mega. Regarding the power PCB I fear that a light bulb could be too much power, I don't know the power it's able to support, and I especially need to evaluate the 5V, where the 12V  light bulb maybe is not fitting. Is it true that powering the mega through the 5V goes in conflict with the USB power input?
